# powerdns or alternatives for hosting multiple domains

Tags: ubuntu, hosting, dns-zone, powerdns

recently I assigned a project to a developer.

My requirements are:

1. host multiple domains/subdomains in a droplet/vps like these at digitalocean.com,
2. use a dns authoritative server,
3. have an automation script capable to create/modify/delete the dns zone records of a client and
4. fit under my current development of php as cgi script with Apache virtual hosts and suexec module.

Developing machine: Ubuntu server.

Developer proposed powerdns and started working with the API (https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/api_spec/) to handle the zones.

My questions are:

1. wouldn't we need sth like the [backends](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/) (namely BIND) to make it work?
2. I can see in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-an-authoritative-only-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial that BIND needs 2 servers to work (master-slave) otherwise the name resolution have validation problems, how this applies to powerdns?
3. in terms of load balancing, will this solution fit in future or even just now so I can send the site visitors to other machines sitting at the background that actually host the sites?
4. I rejected cpanel as it modifies the machine and is not simple to follow my idea of going "light" with minimum resources; what other alternatives do I have here?

Much appreciate your help

Comment: Any of the big dns servers (bind, powerdns certainly) is fit for the task - but you should consider not hosting the dns infrastructure yourself. It is drop dead and much more reliable if distributed over the world. Besides classic hoster which most of them offer dns you can also use eoute53 from Amazon AWS which has a nice web API.

Comment: Hosting websites and online applications does not require you to run your own authoritative name servers, I would recommend to either let your registrar host your DNS (many do that quite well and frequently it is free too) and if they don't offer an API use a DNS hosting provider that does. Then automate your provisioning to use that API. Or  leverage something like https://stackexchange.github.io/dnscontrol/ to control multiple DNS registrar API's from a single interface.

Comment: I found that powerdns has a http API where one can add a zone file using curl: https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/README/